# CAKeyframeAnimation not working in nib

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cakeyframeanimation

I have a nib file that has to animate a view to move in a circular path.
But when I run my code I see the view was not animated and at the top corner of my view

this is my code

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(loadingview.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(loadingview.bounds)), radius: 30, startAngle: 0, endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI)*2, clockwise: true)

        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.beginTime = 0.0
        animation.duration = 1
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        animation.path = circlePath.CGPath

        let squareView = UIView()
        squareView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
        squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        self.addSubview(squareView)
        // You can also pass any unique string value for key


        // circleLayer is only used to locate the circle animation path
        let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        circleLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
        circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        loadingview.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)

        squareView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")

        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    }
```

Comment: please post code use text, not picture, ok?

Comment: Need code to help you

Comment: seems like you need some timing information on that animation https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cakeyframeanimation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot begin an animation in `awakeFromNib`. It is too soon. You can only animate a layer that is actually in your interface's view/layer hierarchy, and a layer of a view that has just come out of the nib, like `loadingview`, has not been placed into the full interface yet.

Also, this would appear to be a CABasicAnimation, not a CAKeyframeAnimation. You need to fix that.

Comment: so i can't add animation to nib ? or should i use like delay to wait it to load ?

Comment: If the view's `window` is `nil`, it is too soon to start an animation. Therefore `didMoveToWindow` is probably the soonest you can sensibly begin. — But you still need to fix your animation; it is not a keyframe animation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the xib first, then in the ViewController in viewDidAppear() method just call yourXib.awakeFromNib()

```
yourXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("yourXib", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
yourXib.awakeFromNib()
```